# Why is my string reversal function having a segmentation fault?

Tags: c

My main suspicion is that i am meant to null terminate the string i'm returning or is it already terminated ?. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

char* reverse(char*);


int main(void) {

printf("%s",reverse("abcde"));
return 0;
}

char* reverse(char* string){
  int length = strlen(string);
  int limit = (int)floor(length/2);
  char temp;

for(int x = 0;x<=limit;x++){
    temp = string[x];
    string[x] = string[length-x-1];
    string[length-x-1] = temp;

}

return string;


}
```

Comment: `"abcde"` is a constant. You cannot change it. This is asked many times before. Looking for duplicate now.

Comment: Why are you flooring an integer division?

Comment: perhaps make another char* variable inside the function and return that instead?

Comment: This is not related to your problem which others have already pointed out, however, you might also consider using a variable name besides string so as not to be confused with the type `string`.

Comment: use **char  a[] = "abcde";** and then pass it to function like **reverse(a)**

Comment: @kishanoza thanks that was the problem